# SQL SELECT Aggregates from two unjoined tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g, count

Is it possible to pull counts from two tables that are not joined?

For example:

```
SELECT
     (SELECT COUNT(PERSON) FROM PEOPLE),
     COUNT(BUILDINGS)
FROM 
     BUILDINGS
```

I get an error saying:

> not a single-group group function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is by moving both count queries in the `select` clause:

```
select
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PEOPLE) people_cnt,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BUILDINGS) building_cnt
from dual
```

Comment: Thank you!  I used this solution.